# swing loose phrase in the sentence

Tags: meaning

From The Godfather:

Fanucci was shot by Vito Corleone:

> Fanucci was holding on to the sides of the door, trying to stand
>   erect, trying to reach for his gun. The force of his struggle had torn
>   the buttons off on his jacket and made it ***swing loose***.

I didn't get the meaning of `swing loose`. Couldn't you give some explnantion?

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loose

Comment: @TRomano The meaning of loose is quite clear, instead I was confused by the meaning swing loose.

Comment: Made it swing = caused it to swing http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swing

Comment: @TRomano Here, swing = to move smoothly in a curve, huh?

Comment: A jacket has buttons that run from the collar bone down the front of the body. Depending on the length of the jacket, the lowest button could be near the knees or just below the belt. When the buttons have been ripped off, the two front pieces of the jacket, which normally cover the torso, flap like tent flaps when the wind blows, if the flaps are not zippered shut or tied shut.

Answer (score 4):

"Swing loose" here refers to his jacket. The struggle tore the buttons off of the jacket, so it had nothing to hold it closed, and the flaps of the jacket were "swinging loose" or hanging freely (i.e. not clasped).